# Getting error in Oracle PL/SQL procedure: ORA-30625

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I want to compare average color of image in Oracle SQL database with some specific RGB color. I found similar function in documentation, but I'm getting some error. Can anyone help me, please?

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compareAvgColor (
    red IN integer,
    green IN integer,
    blue IN integer,
    image IN SI_STILLIMAGE
) RETURN double precision
AS
    myColor SI_Color;
    myAvgColor SI_AverageColor;
BEGIN
    myColor := NEW SI_Color(null, null, null);
    myColor.SI_RGBColor(red, green, blue);
    myAvgColor := NEW SI_AverageColor(myColor);
    return myAvgColor.SI_Score(image);
END;
```

Select query:

```
SELECT i.id, compareAvgColor(0, 255, 0, i.image) as similarity
FROM images i
```

**Error:**

> ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

Comment: Show us the SI_Color constructor method too.

Comment: @jarlh presumably it is this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10829/mm_stimgref004.htm

Comment: Are there records in the table where `image` is NULL?

Comment: Thank you, @DaveCosta, so much! Simple condition (`IF image IS NULL THEN return 100; END IF;)` solved my problem.